# does bundle fetch the same gem twice when they are required in 2 different Gemfiles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, bundle

So suppose 1 Gemfile uses devise 1.0 and another one also requires that same gem. Does bundle/rvm actually keeps 2 copies of the gem devise 1.0 when there are 2 different gemsets, one for each gemfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends from the gemset used. When you run `bundle install` it will compile a `Gemfile.lock` with the required gems and fix the gem at the highest version available at that time (unless you specify an exact version or a different version with `~>` syntax).

Then when you add new gems to your Gemfile it still use that version unless you use the `bundle update devise` command. So as far as you not update manually devise it will use always the same gem.

Rvm will reuse the same gem if it's compatible with the second Gemfile **and** you're in the same [gemset](http://beginrescueend.com/gemsets/basics/) otherwise it will install a second copy of the devise gem.

To avoid that you can add shared gem in the `@global` gemset and they will be available to all your gemsets.

In every case it should not be an issue since a gem does not use a lot of disk space and different versions are handled using rvm/Gemfiles.